# Making custom notifications match default style

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications, remoteview

I'm struggling with creating a custom notification whose expanded view is defined by a `RemoteView` using a `bigContentView`.

I'd like for this notification to look exactly like a default notification however I'm having issues achieving this across all platforms.

I can pull the font size and color of the title and description using `@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title` however I can't seem to find a way to determine what positioning to use for those titles and descriptions (margins, padding).

I also can't seem to determine what icon size or background to use for the icon. For example on some devices, there is a light blue background that appears behind the notification icon, but on Samsungs this doesn't seem to be the case.